# What do the Guava JavaDocs mean by sets being based on different "equivalence relations"?

Tags: java, collections, set, guava, equivalence

The Guava [JavaDocs](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/24.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#union-java.util.Set-java.util.Set-) for `Sets.SetView.union()` (as well as `intersection()`, `difference()`, and `symmetricDifference()`) mention "equivalence relations":

> Results are undefined if `set1` and `set2` are sets based on different equivalence relations (as `HashSet`, `TreeSet`, and the `Map.keySet()` of an `IdentityHashMap` all are).

I struggle to understand the meaning of that sentence.

The glossary [defines "equivalence relation"](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/GuavaTermsExplained#equivalence-relation) as [reflexive](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/GuavaTermsExplained#reflexive) ("`a.relation(a)` is always `true`"), [symmetric](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/GuavaTermsExplained#symmetric) (`a1.relation(a2) == a2.relation(a1)`) and [transitive](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/GuavaTermsExplained#transitive) (`a1.relation(a2) && a2.relation(a3)` implies `a1.relation(a3)`) - and refers to [`Object.equals()`' docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)). (Unfortunately, the [Guava wiki](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#sets) doesn't go into any detail...

But how are the different types of `Set` different in that respect (i.e. equivalence relations)? They all seem to inherit [`equals()` from `AbstractSet`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/util/AbstractSet.java#AbstractSet.equals%28java.lang.Object%29)? It doesn't have to do with the type of object a set holds (e.g. `Set<Cow>` vs. `Set<Chicken>`), does it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like they are referring to when a `Set` doesn't use `equals` and `hashCode` to compare elements for some reason. The most common example of this is a `TreeSet` with a custom `Comparator`. For example, we could have something like this:

```
Set<String> a = new TreeSet<>();
Set<String> b = new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

The union, intersection, etc. of `a` and `b` are undefined, because `a` and `b` have different equivalence relations defined between elements.

Java SE also makes mention of this kind of situation when it's talking about ordering which is inconsistent with `equals` (see [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)):

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be *consistent with equals* if it is to correctly implement the `Set` interface. (See `Comparable` or `Comparator` for a precise definition of *consistent with equals*.) This is so because the `Set` interface is defined in terms of the `equals` operation, but a `TreeSet` instance performs all element comparisons using its `compareTo` (or `compare`) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal. The behavior of a set *is* well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the `Set` interface.

Comment: This puzzles me a little. It seems easy enough to me to implement `Sets.union` so that it works as expected for different equivalence relations. A Set is just a predicate and an iterator, so a `union(a, b)` is just `contains(x): a.contains(x) && b.contains(x)` and `iterator(): a.iterator().concat(b.iterator().filter(x -> ! a.contains(x)))`

Maybe there's some subtlety to java.util.Set that I'm missing, where this simple implementation becomes problematic for Sets with different equivalence relations?

Comment: @MikeFHay I think the issue is creating a `Set` for the union result in a way that makes sense. [Here's a short example.](https://ideone.com/mRlF0k) When e.g. using sets backed by an `IdentityHashMap`, we'd have to return the result in another identity set, otherwise it would seem "incorrect" because duplicate elements (according to the `Set` contract) would be removed. If we did return the result in an identity set, it would mess up the union for normal sets. This could be partially solved if Java had a better cloning API, but not for cases when the sets have different equivalence relations.

Comment: I don't think your example accurately represents the issue. The Guava docs say `Results are undefined if set1 and set2 are sets based on different equivalence relations`, but in your example you're making a union of two sets which have the same equivalence relation (identity).

Also Guava's `union` is a view - it doesn't actually create a new set, just implements the Set interface using the existing Sets, as I described in my comment. The problem you hit of choosing a new implementation isn't a problem with this approach.

Comment: @MikeFHay If you mix sets with different equivalence relations, the problems are the same as what my example points out. Using the sets in my example, the union could be either `[X,X]` or `[X]`, depending on which equivalence relation is used. In the case of Guava, the way the iteration order is defined by the JavaDoc, you would actually get different sets for `union(a,b)` and `union(b,a)`, which is pretty bad since a union should be commutative. [Here's a paste of a Guava example.](https://pastebin.com/TNcgr0PG)